# Displaying mysql results inside a table using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple webpage setup for delivering media content from a mysql database, but after my hosts upgraded my server, the site went down.
It was created many years ago so this was to be expected.
I have attempted to update my code to current standards, but I am still not getting any results from my query.
The page opens but does not return anything past the header.
I have run the code through a couple of php syntax checkers and no faults are detected.
could somebody possible suggest where I am going wrong.
I have not done any coding for 7yrs or so, so finding the fault is taking way longer than it should.
Here is the full code from my index.php

```
<?php 
    include 'header.php'; 
    include 'welcome.php';
    include 'musicDb.php';
    include 'analyticstracking.php';

    /* MAIN QUERY */
    $query_recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM setinfo ORDER BY setid DESC";
    $recordset1 = mysqli_query($query_recordset1, $musicDb) or die(mysqli_error());
    $row_recordset1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recordset1);
    $totalRows_recordset1 = mysqli_num_rows($recordset1);
?>

<tr>
    <td>
        
        <table align="center">

            <!-- LOOP THROUGH RESULTS AND DISPLAY ALL RESULTS -->
            <?php do { ?>

                <tr CLASS="data_left" >
                    <td><a href="<?php echo $row_recordset1['id'];?>.php"><img width="200" HEIGHT="200" src="<?php echo $row_recordset1['artwork']; ?>" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr><td><a href="player.php?TargetSet=<?php echo $row_recordset1['setid'];?>"><?php echo $row_recordset1['setname'];?></td></tr>  
                            <tr><td><?php echo $row_recordset1['dj'] ; ?> </td></tr>
                            <tr><td><?php echo $row_recordset1['bpm'] ; ?>bpm <?php echo $row_recordset1['genre'] ; ?> (<?php echo $row_recordset1['era'] ;?>) </td></tr>
                            <tr><td><?php echo $row_recordset1['length'] ; ?> </td></tr>
                            <tr><td><?php echo $row_recordset1['date'] ; ?> </td></tr>
                        </table>
                                                
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr height="50" ><td colspan="4"><img src="images/lineindex.png" /></td></tr>
                <tr height="50" ></tr>

            <!-- END LOOP -->
            <?php } while ($row_recordset1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($recordset1)); ?>

        </table>

<!-- LINK TO FOOTER -->
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

I also created a test file to check my raw query is still working, and it does retrun the data.

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("*****", "*****", "*****", "*****");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM setinfo ORDER BY setid DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 
        " " . $row["artwork"]. 
        " " . $row["setid"]. 
        " " . $row["dj"]. 
        " " . $row["setname"]. 
        ": " . $row["bpm"]. 
        ": " . $row["length"]. 
        ": " . $row["date"].
        ": " . $row["file"].
        ": " . $row["filesize"].
        
        "<br><br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Your "test" uses `while()` while your original code uses `do{}while`. Use `while()` in your original code

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I have tried to replace the do loop with a while, but I still don't get a response. I don't seem to be able to post my edited code in the reply because of the character restriction.

Comment: I have now got there in the end, I had a typo stopping your suggestion working. Thank you very much for pointing me back on track.